# How to set Cookies in webview_flutter?

Tags: flutter, cookies, webview

How can I set Cookies in webview_flutter during initialization?

```
body: WebView
    initialUrl: index_url,
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
      _controller=webViewController;
    },
    javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
      _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
    ].toSet(),       
    onPageFinished: (String url) {
      print('Page finished loading: $url');
    },
  ),
```

Comment: Setting cookies is not officially supported by Flutter as of December 2019.  There is currently an open PR for adding `getCookies` and `setCookies` methods to the `CookieManager` class, but this has not been merged and implemented yet.

Comment: You can try to use a different webview which has much more features then the beta version from flutter  https://github.com/pichillilorenzo/flutter_inappwebview

Answer (score 6):

Anyone still looking for an answer, the latest version of [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) (`webview_flutter: ^3.0.0`) includes the `initialCookies` param which takes a list of `WebViewCookie`.

eg.

```
sessionCookie = WebViewCookie(
      name: 'my_session_cookie',
      value: 'cookie_value',
      domain: 'www.mydomain.com',
);

WebView(
initialCookies: [sessionCookie],
...
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set cookie using Tow methods.

**Solution 1.** 
Using `webViewController.evaluateJavascript()` 
Eg:

```
    final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
    Completer<WebViewController>();
    WebViewController _webViewController;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.future.then((controller) {
      _webViewController = controller;
        _webViewController.loadUrl(URL);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child:
               WebView(
            debuggingEnabled: true,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            onPageFinished: (String value) {
              setSession(sessionId, _webViewController);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

void setSession(String sessionId, WebViewController webViewController) async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
   await webViewController.evaluateJavascript("document.cookie = 'ASP.NET_SessionId=$sessionId'");
  } else {
   await webViewController.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie = "ASP.NET_SessionId=$sessionId; path=/"');
  }
 }
```

but using this we can set cookies after `onPageFinished` in WebView. This solution will work only after you reload the webview. That means on the first build this method will add cookies to the WebView and will get result after second time onwards.
If you want WebView to load with preset Cookies check the next Solution

**Solution 2.** Using `headers` we can set cookies while initiating an http request. Eg:

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
    Completer<WebViewController>();
    WebViewController _webViewController;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.future.then((controller) {
      _webViewController = controller;
      Map<String, String> header = {'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=$sessionId'};
      _webViewController.loadUrl(URL, headers: header);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child:
               WebView(
            debuggingEnabled: true,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This will load WebView with given Cookie.

Comment: You can clear cookies using 
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager();
bool hadCookies = await cookieManager.clearCookies();

Comment: Did you ever try the second approach ? Looks like setting the cookie does not seem to work via the headers. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/27597

Comment: Am using the second approach now to set cookie, and it is working fine. @TeeJaay Try to clear the cookie before setting new one.

Comment: hi can u plz tell where to get $sessionId

Comment: Simply inspect the Webpage and select Application>Storage>Cookies there you can find Session_ID

Comment: @deepakraj can u post a sample code, 2nd approach does not seem to work

Comment: I think the answer has required code. Just use the same.

Comment: I used second way but nothing is happen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65001831/webview-flutter-failed-to-set-the-cookie-into-header-when-initialize-url @deepakraj

Comment: @sayreskabir can you provide the URL you are testing.?

Comment: https://ipb.parsian-bank.ir/HDMap/Mobile2.php?BranchName=&latitude=35.7312303&longitude=51.4330587 @deepakraj

Comment: @sayreskabir you can replace Map<String, String> header = {'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=$sessionId'}; with Map<String, String> header = {'Cookie':'cookiesession1=$sessionId'};

Comment: This is my complete code : https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/htZk4YxcQs/ . in `onPageFinished` i try to print my cookie `String cookies =
                      await wvc.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');` but `String cookies` is empty?@deepakraj

Comment: _webViewController.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie') will return an empty string because you are setting cookies in the header, not in the javascript.

Comment: Then how can i get cookie from header?@deepakraj

Answer (score 2):

With flutter `1.22.1` it works for me the following way:

```
WebView(
  onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
    controller.loadUrl(
      "https://mypage.de/",
      headers: {"Cookie": "mycookie=true"},
    );
  },
)
```

Notice that there is no colon in `Cookie` as other answers suggested.

**Update**: Works with flutter 2 as well.

Answer (score 1):

@deepakraj I have been trying to get one of those to work with no luck. The second one is the one I am most interested in. So Here is my code. I am simulating a leading async request to my backend which needs to resolve first in order to build the webview (source of the header) which is why I use a futureBuilder. Maybe I am having a glaring issue here.

```
 WebViewController _webViewController;
  Future ssoRequestFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    this.ssoRequestFuture = makeGetRequest();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<http.Response>(
        future: this.ssoRequestFuture,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
            case ConnectionState.none:
              return Text('Not connected');
            case ConnectionState.active:
            case ConnectionState.waiting:
              return Text('waiting');
            case ConnectionState.done:
              var cookieStr = snapshot.data.headers['set-cookie'];
              List<String> cookies = cookieStr.split(","); // I am not interested n the first cookie
              Cookie ssoCookie = Cookie.fromSetCookieValue(cookies[1]);
              Map<String, String> header = {'Cookie': '$ssoCookie'};
              // clear cookies was a suggestion ??
              CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager();
              cookieManager.clearCookies();

              return Scaffold(
                body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {
                  _controller.future.then((controller) {
                    _webViewController = controller;
                    _webViewController.loadUrl('http://192.168.86.28:4205', headers: header);
                  });

                  return WebView(
                    debuggingEnabled: true,
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                      _controller.complete(webViewController);
                    },                 
                    gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
                  );
                }),
              );
            default:
              return Text('Default');
          }
        }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webview_cookie_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_cookie_manager) package along with `webview_flutter`. It works:

```
await cookieManager.setCookies([
              Cookie('cookieName', 'cookieValue')
                ..domain = 'youtube.com'
                ..expires = DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 10))
                ..httpOnly = false
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is latest example with package webview_flutter: ^4.4.1

```
WebViewController controller = WebViewController();

WebViewCookie cookie = WebViewCookie(
      name: "cookie_name", value: "cookies_value", domain: 
 "your_domain.com");
  WebViewCookieManager().setCookie(cookie);
  controller..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
  controller..loadRequest(Uri.parse(baseUrl));

 WebViewWidget(
    controller: controller,
  );
```

**WebView(
initialCookies: [sessionCookie],
...
),**
this is now deprecated