# WebView flutter: Failed to set the 'cookie' into header when initialize url

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

I am using `webview_flutter: ^1.0.7` to shows web page on my application:

```
WebView(
     initialMediaPlaybackPolicy: AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow,
     javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
     onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) async {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
```

in initState method i have these codes:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    cookieManagerr.clearCookies();    
    _controller.future.then((controller) async {
      wvc = controller;
      // wvc.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie = "SESSION-Test=token";');
      Map<String, String> header = {'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=222'};
      wvc.loadUrl(
        '${widget.url}?BranchName=&latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}',
        headers: header,
      );
    });
  }
```

but after running nothing is added to header.

If i change my code to this:

```
 WebView(
                initialMediaPlaybackPolicy:
                    AutoMediaPlaybackPolicy.always_allow,
                initialUrl:
                    '${widget.url}?BranchName=&latitude=${latitude}&longitude=${longitude}',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (webViewController) async {
                  webViewController.evaluateJavascript(
                      'document.cookie = "SESSION-Test=token";');
```

I got this error:

```
I/chromium( 6239): [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Access is denied for this document.", source:  (1)
D/EGL_emulation( 6239): eglMakeCurrent: 0xd2aea420: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xb48e41f0)
I/chromium( 6239): [INFO:CONSOLE(17932)] "You are using OSRM's demo server. Please note that it is **NOT SUITABLE FOR PRODUCTION USE**.
```

How to set cookie that works on ios and android?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, maybe there is problem with your html. For example, https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/531 says that if the script is executed inside an iframe with a sandbox attribute, it can throw an error.

Secondly, what about trying to use another way instead of cookies? For example, to pass some variables to javascript from flutter, you can:

1. `webViewController.evaluateJavascript('window.hello="world";')`
2. or, you can `webViewController.evaluateJavascript('window.your_js_method("world");')`

Comment: I try to load this url for test : `https://ipb.parsian-bank.ir/HDMap/Mobile2.php?BranchName=&latitude=35.7312303&longitude=51.4330587` and i change set cookie inside initstate `wvc.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie="SESSION-Test=token";');`  but i got `"Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': Access is denied for this document.", source:  (1)` !! It is not possible to set cookie in this site ?  this is my code https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/WGNtrVjbwz/ @ch271828n
`

Comment: @sayreskabir Sounds like the restriction on that webpage? It looks like a bank so I expect it has special tricks on js security. Firstly, try your cookie technique on *another webpage* which you know is very weak in security.

Comment: @sayreskabir hi, did you solve it? If so, you can mark this answer as accepted and give a vote up :)

Comment: I will try to change my url and then I will tested.For now I change my url to https://flutter.dev/ or https://stackoverflow.com/ but i still get `Uncaught SecurityError`. @ch271828n

Comment: @sayreskabir Hmm that is a problem... Do you see problems on ios? if so that maybe a restriction on the underlying webview in android.

Comment: When i use `WebviewCookieManager` library it is possible to set cookie to my site and cookie is set but in my way or yours, cookie is not set  @ch271828n