# How to automatically accept/remove cookie from Webview with flutter?

Tags: flutter, cookies

I try to load a facebook groupe webview with flutter, but when I load the Webview, facebook display a page about cookie but I have no button to accept. So I try to found a solution to remove this page and access to the facebook group view.

I tried to create a button to get cookie but I have "" nothing...

Here is my code :

```
  late WebViewController _webViewController;
```

---

```
   Stack(
   children: <Widget>[
    new Card(
       elevation: 5,
       shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
       color: Colors.white,
       child :WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/380510889507267',

          gestureRecognizers: [
          Factory(() => PlatformViewVerticalGestureRecognizer()),
          ].toSet(),

      )
    ),
      MaterialButton(
         color: Colors.white,
         shape: CircleBorder(),
         child:Icon(Icons.cookie,color: Colors.red),
                onPressed: () async {
                 final  cookies = await _webViewController.runJavascriptReturningResult(
                  'document.cookie',
                 );
               print("$cookies");
              },
            ),
           ]
         )
```

Comment: When I view the page with my regular Chrome browser, I don't see an option for Accepting any Cookies.

Comment: I tried on my Android phone, I don't see an option to accept cookies

Comment: for facebook it's little hide, it need to clic on privacy policy text link, after it show the cookie... I search a more user friendly solution

Comment: I don't see a "Privacy Policy" link in the provided URL. Can you share a photo/Gif of how to access the "cookies" popup?

Comment: How do the cookies appear? what do you need to click on for them appear?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from here:
[How to set Cookies in webview_flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751391/how-to-set-cookies-in-webview-flutter/60389501#60389501)

Using headers we can set cookies while initiating an http request. Eg:

```
final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
    Completer<WebViewController>();
    WebViewController _webViewController;

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _controller.future.then((controller) {
      _webViewController = controller;
      Map<String, String> header = {'Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=$sessionId'};
      _webViewController.loadUrl(URL, headers: header);
    });
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Container(
          child:
               WebView(
            debuggingEnabled: true,
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

This will load web view with given cookie.
If I misunderstood please comment and let me know.

Comment: Thank you, just what is $sessionId ?

Comment: in https://www.facebook.com/groups/380510889507267 inspector -> Application>Storage>Cookies  i can't found Session_ID. I have Presence, xs, C_user , fr, sb, datr

Comment: @Nitneuq I just gave an example you can replace session is with the name of your cookie.

Comment: Also, do you want to set cookies while opening the url or after sometime when user presses a button( for example). If first case, then you can set headers as I gave above and if second case then go to the link I gave and read solution 1

Comment: I prefer first with auto set coolie while opening url. How to know name of cookie ? It’s url ?

Comment: I tried to replace sessionId by all cookie name  Presence, xs, C_user , fr, sb, datr     but I can't display facebook page

Comment: I think that you should first take to user to sign in to their facebook account because all other cookies are available when user has signed in to the group.

Answer (score -1):

The webview is missing the controller

```dart
onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _webViewController = webViewController;
        },
```

Please add the above lines in WebView

```dart
child :WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/380510889507267',
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
          _webViewController = webViewController;
        },
          gestureRecognizers: [
          Factory(() => PlatformViewVerticalGestureRecognizer()),
          ].toSet(),

      )
```

**Edit**
Enable javascript

```
WebView(
       initialUrl: 'https://www.facebook.com/groups/380510889507267' ,
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
      ),
```

**EDIT**

try using evalJavascript

replace

```
final  cookies = await _webViewController.runJavascriptReturningResult(
                  'document.cookie',
                 );
```

with

```
final  cookies =  await _webViewController.evaluateJavascript('document.cookie');
```

Comment: I have already test, it's because I remove from exemple but, no change

Comment: Try adding javascript mode. Edited my answer too

Comment: also test :( but no change

Comment: Add a print inside onwebviewcreated method to see if the controller is assigned

Comment: Yes it well print

Comment: Edited my answer. Use evaluate javascript

Comment: I have some errors with evaluateJavascript, it seems depreciated

Comment: Whats the error?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_cookie_manager try this package

Comment: Did you manage to get the cookies?