# Using WebViewCookieManager.setCookie of webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview-flutter

I'm quite new to Flutter. Currently I'm facing with problem of usage package `webview_flutter` from [flutter docs](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) at latest version (which is `4.0.7`) for initial cookie when calling `Webview` in Flutter

> WebView.initialCookies has been removed. Use WebViewCookieManager.setCookie before calling WebViewController.loadRequest.

Currently Flutter has change method `WebView` with controller into `WebViewWidget` with controller.

This is my new code for initialize `WebView`

```dart
_webViewController = WebViewController()
  ..loadRequest(
    Uri.parse("https://flutter.dev/"),
  )
  ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
  ..setNavigationDelegate(NavigationDelegate(
    onPageStarted: (url) {
      print("come here: $url");
    },
    onPageFinished: (url) async {
      final cookies = await _webViewController.runJavaScriptReturningResult(
        'document.cookie',
      );
      // I can get cookie when page is reload or go to next page here
      print("cookie: $cookies");
    },
  ));
```

This is for build view

```dart
// view build
return Stack(
  children: [
    WebViewWidget(
      controller: widget.controller,
    ),
  ],
);
```

I can get website cookie everytime it reloads or go to next page by catch action `onPageFinished`. But the problem is I want to initalize URL with `initialCookies` when taping into Webview.

The answer currently is for [webview_flutter: ^3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57751391/how-to-set-cookies-in-webview-flutter) so it currently can't be use for latest version.

Thank you a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those who looking for an answer with version `4.0.0+` just like me.

This is my answer

```dart
WebViewCookie cookie =
    WebViewCookie(name: "sessionId", value: "12345678", domain: widget.url);
// Flutter has change to this
WebViewCookieManager().setCookie(cookie);
_webViewController = WebViewController()
  ..loadRequest(
    Uri.parse(widget.url),
  );
```

**Note:** Domain must be as same as the url when you call widget unless it will not call.

Comment: How can I add max-age or expiration attributes using WebViewCookie?

Comment: what about WebViewCookie in flutter web build?

Comment: That's a very strange API. if I have multiple instances that should not be sharing cookies. They will be. No other option.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with `initialUrl` & `onPageFinished` params

```
String initialUrl = "https://flutter.dev/";
String cookie = "session_id=12345";

WebViewWidget(
  controller: widget.controller,
  initialUrl: '$initialUrl?cookie=$cookie',
  onPageFinished: (url) async {
    final cookies = await _webViewController.runJavaScriptReturningResult(
      'document.cookie',
    );
    print("cookie: $cookies");
  },
);
```

Comment: Currently I'm using ``webview_flutter: ^4.0.7`` but I don't see any methods like your ``initialUrl`` or ``onPageFinished``. Do you use some different packages?

Answer (score 0):

This is latest example with package webview_flutter: ^4.4.1

```
WebViewController controller = WebViewController();

WebViewCookie cookie = WebViewCookie(
      name: "cookie_name", value: "cookies_value", domain: 
 "your_domain.com");
  WebViewCookieManager().setCookie(cookie);
  controller..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted);
  controller..loadRequest(Uri.parse(baseUrl));

 WebViewWidget(
    controller: controller,
  );
```

**WebView(
initialCookies: [sessionCookie],
...
),**
this is now deprecated